# Using Google Apps Script How do i hit any URL?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script How do i hit any URL?

In instance ,i want such a code in apps script that work same like the java code works that i have provided below .

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [URL Fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) service to connect to a URL.

```
 try {
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
   Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log(e.toString());
 }
```